# Get recoird id Error attemp to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, parameters

I'm using
`apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get(‘id’)`

but when i run the class the developer console returns:

> attemp to de-reference a null object

this is the url: ...sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0060100000AKKvUAAX/view

If i set the id manually class runs, but if i set the id using the code the error apears

Answer (score 1):

You should get the Id from the controller using the `getId()` method.

```
public MyExtensionConstructor(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    Id recordId = controller.getId();
}
```